# Can I read the state of controls in non-UI threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Can I read the state of controls (not change it) in non-UI threads like this

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(notifyIcon.BalloonTipText))
{
    // ...
}
```

Is it safe?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: @Clive DM Because it can be some sort of undefined behavior

Comment: You mean like before the controls are initialized?

Comment: The question is pretty clear, although a bit terse. He wants to know if it is safe to *read* the state (properties etc.) of controls from a different thread than the one that created/owns it. The answer is no, as Amit has answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx) artice from Visual Studio Magazine about Multithreading in WinForms.

As explained on page 2, one of the problems of accessing UI controls from a thread other than the thread that created the control is that that thread doesn't have a message pump (or at least not necessarily has one). "Reading" UI controls state is done through window messages (for example, [WM_GETTEXT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632627(v=vs.85).aspx)) just as writing to them, and this is wrong in the same way.

Comment: NotifyIcon is not a control though, so it has no Invoke method either. The BalloonTipText property has a very simple getter/setter with no event invokes or native windows access. I would say just to use simple locks here.

Comment: @taffer - maybe, but that depends on what the question is... is it "*Can I read the state of controls in non-UI threads*", or is it can I deal with a NotifyIcon in a non-UI thread?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property named "InvokedRequired" in every control. Check for this property, if it is false you can call method in regular way, otherwise call invoke method with the help of delegate from the control you are trying to access.